# How to Listen to JavaScript CallBack from SwiftUI?

Tags: javascript, swiftui, wkwebview

I am new in SwiftUI I have created WebView like this in SwiftUI

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var title: String
    var url: URL
    var loadStatusChanged: ((Bool, Error?) -> Void)? = nil

    func makeCoordinator() -> WebView.Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let view = WKWebView()
        view.navigationDelegate = context.coordinator
        view.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        // you can access environment via context.environment here
        // Note that this method will be called A LOT
    }

    func onLoadStatusChanged(perform: ((Bool, Error?) -> Void)?) -> some View {
        var copy = self
        copy.loadStatusChanged = perform
        return copy
    }

    class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate,WKScriptMessageHandler {
        @State private var studentAppID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "studentAppID")
        let parent: WebView

        init(_ parent: WebView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didCommit navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print(webView.url as Any)
            parent.loadStatusChanged?(true, nil)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
            print(webView as Any)
            print(webView.url as Any)
            parent.title = webView.title ?? ""
            webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByName('applnID')[0].value='\(studentAppID!)'", completionHandler: nil)
            parent.loadStatusChanged?(false, nil)
        }

        func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFail navigation: WKNavigation!, withError error: Error) {
            parent.loadStatusChanged?(false, error)
        }
        
        func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
//            guard let dict = message.body as? [String : AnyObject] else {
//                return
//            }
            
            print(message.body)
        }

    }
}
```

I want to configure function so that I can received response from WebView when user click on the  button tag on the WebView
I found the code for this in swift but don't understand how can I used it in SwiftUI
The code is like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, WKScriptMessageHandler {
  let content = """
  <!DOCTYPE html><html><body>
  <button onclick="onClick()">Click me</button>
  <script>
  function onClick() {
    window.webkit.messageHandlers.backHomePage.postMessage("success");
  }
  </script>
  </body></html>
  """

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    config.userContentController = WKUserContentController()
    config.userContentController.add(self, name: "backHomePage")

    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200), configuration: config)

    view.addSubview(webView)

    webView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: nil)
  }

  func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
    print(message.body)
  }
}
```

as flow in this link

[How to receive callback in ios from javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181852/how-to-receive-callback-in-ios-from-javascript)

Can I configure same in SwiftUI if yes then how?

Comment: `@State` is for use inside a View. Not a class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have implemented is correct however you have missed out on `WKWebViewConfiguration` object.

You need to create web view configuration that registers a message handler for your javascript code to call, see below:

1. Create a class that can receive callbacks from JavaScript code:

   ```
   let scriptMessageHandler = ScriptMessageHandler()

   class ScriptMessageHandler: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
       func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
           print(message.body)
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create a config object and pass an object of `ScriptMessageHandler` as handler.

   ````
   let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()
   config.userContentController = WKUserContentController()
   config.userContentController.add(scriptMessageHandler, name: "backHomePage")```
   ````

You can do this in your `makeUIView(context:) -> WKWebView` method implementation, right before you create Web View object and pass this config to your web view.

In Javascript, above config can then be called like below:

```
function onClick() {
   window.webkit.messageHandlers.backHomePage.postMessage("success");
}
```

When above function is called from JavaScript, you will get a callback in your `userContentController(_ didReceive:)` implementation.

Comment: I understand but how can I do this in SwiftUI and where?

Comment: If I can config code in makeUIView(context:) -> WKWebView it shows me error. Not possible to call it there

Comment: @Muju As I mentioned in the answer, you can create configuration in your `makeUIView(context:) -> WKWebView` method implementation, right before you create Web View object and pass this config to your web view object. And you need to pass Coordinator object in place of `self` as you have set that as delegate to receive callbacks

Comment: If I write your code in  makeUIView(context:) -> WKWebView it show me error Argument type 'WebView' does not conform to expected type 'WKScriptMessageHandler' even I write WKScriptMessageHandler next to WKWebView still showing error

Comment: Can you write whole code?

Comment: Did you write your code in makeUIView(context:) -> WKWebView and check it still shows error

Comment: My bad @Muju, you will need a Class that can receive and handle callbacks, I have updated my answer.

Comment: still the same error Argument type 'WebView.ScriptMessageHandler.Type' does not conform to expected type 'WKScriptMessageHandler'

Comment: @Muju you need to use the object, not the class itself. `scriptMessageHandler` instead of `ScriptMessageHandler`. :)

Comment: How can I pass message.body to other view?

Answer (score 0):

Base on @KishanSadhwani's answer, bellow is a test-passed example:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

let testHTML = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello Alert</title>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="showAlert()">Click me to send message to native app</button>

<script>
    function showAlert() {
        window.webkit.messageHandlers.NAME.postMessage("[MESSAGE TO APP]");
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>

"""

class LogBookScriptMessageHandler: NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print(message.body)
    }
}

struct LogBookWebView: UIViewRepresentable {
    typealias UIViewType = WKWebView

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let config = WKWebViewConfiguration()

        let handler = LogBookScriptMessageHandler()
        config.userContentController.add(handler, name: "NAME")

        let webView = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: config)

        webView.loadHTMLString(testHTML, baseURL: nil)

        return webView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {

    }
}

#Preview {
    LogBookWebView()
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I checked this at my own and its working fine for me.

```
struct WebView: UIViewRepresentable {
            func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
                let coordinator = makeCoordinator()
                let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
                userContentController.add(coordinator, name: "bridge")
                let configuration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
                configuration.userContentController = userContentController
                let wkwebview = WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: configuration)
                wkwebview.navigationDelegate = coordinator
                return wkwebview
            }
    
        func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
                let content = """
                  <!DOCTYPE html>
                  <html>
                  <head>
                  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover">
                  </head>
                  <body>
                  <button>click me</button>
                  <hr/>
                  <div id="log"></div>
                  <script>
                    const log = (msg) => {
                      const p = document.createElement('p')
                      p.textContent = msg
                      document.querySelector('#log').append(p)
                    }
                    // to receive messages from native
                    webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.onMessage = (msg) => {
                      log('from native:' + msg)
                    }
        
                    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
                      log(typeof webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.postMessage)
                      // send messages to native
                      webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.postMessage('{"msg": "hello?","id": ' + Date.now() + '}')
                    })
                  </script>
                  </body>
                  </html>
                  """
                uiView.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: nil)
            }
    
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            return Coordinator()
        }
    
        class Coordinator: NSObject, WKNavigationDelegate, WKScriptMessageHandler {
    
            private var webView: WKWebView?
    
            func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
                self.webView = webView
                print("WebView: navigation finished")
            }
    
            func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: WKWebView) {
                print("Loaded: \(String(describing: webView.url))")
            }
    
            func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
                print("Loaded: \(String(describing: webView.url))")
        
    
            }
        
        // this method is used to get the message from the Webview
                func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
                    print("Signal: \(message.body)")
                    messageToWebview(msg: "iOS Native")
                }
        
        // this method is used to send the message to the Webview
                func messageToWebview(msg: String) {
                    self.webView?.evaluateJavaScript("webkit.messageHandlers.bridge.onMessage('\(msg)')")
                }
            }
    }
```

Hope this will help for you